# Using Pointers In C swapping three numbers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

 int a, b,c; 

  /* Input a and b */

 scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b,&c);

   while(a != -1) {

   int *x = &a;

   int *y = &b;

   int *z = &c;

   printf("Original inputs:   a:%d\tb:%d\tc:%d\n", a, b,c);     

   reorder(a,b,c);  

   swap(a,b);

   printf("Rearranged inputs: a:%d\tb:%d\tc:%d\n\n", a, b,c);  

   break;

   }

   }

void reorder(int *x, int *y, int *z){


 if(*x > *y)

 {

  int temp = *x;

  *x = *y;

  *y = temp;

  }else if(*y > *z){

  int temp = *y;

  *y = *z;


  *z = temp;

  }else if(*x > *z){

  int temp = *x;

  *x = *z;

  *z = temp;    

  }

  }


 void swap(int *px, int *py)
 {

 int temp;

 temp = *px;

 *px = *py;

 *py = temp;

  }
```

I am new to C and learning pointers am not sure how to implement pointers to swap 3 numbers in ascending order

Comment: `reorder(a,b,c);  swap(a,b);` --> `reorder(x,y,z);  swap(x,y);` ?

Comment: A decent compiler should tell you there are serious problems with that code.

Comment: am using devc++ and its giving me two warnings only after making that change mentioned above.

Comment: Put prototype as `void reorder(int *x, int *y, int *z);
void swap(int *px, int *py);` before `main`.

Comment: Also `reorder` is insufficiently processed

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/UBaDsU)

Comment: don't ignore "warnings", make sure your code compiles clean before running it

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a way to start:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void reorder(int* x, int* y, int* z) {
    if (*x > *y) {
        swap(x, y);
    }
    if (*y > *z) {
        swap(y, z);
    }
    if (*z > *x) {
        swap(z, x);
    }
}

int main() {

   int a, b, c; 
   scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
   int *x = &a;
   int *y = &b;
   int *z = &c;
   reorder(x, y, z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your purpose :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reorder(int *, int *, int *);
void swap(int *, int  *);

void main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter three numbers : ");
    while (scanf("%i %i %i", &a, &b, &c)==3)
    {
        reorder(&a, &b, &c);
        printf("Now a is %d, b is %d and c is %d.\n\n", a, b, c);
        printf("Enter three numbers : ");
    }
}


void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void reorder(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    if (*c<*a&&*c<*b)
        swap(a, c);
    if (*b<*a&&*b<*c)
        swap(a, b);
    if (*c<*b)
        swap(b, c);
}
```